# What is the best practise for padding or margin in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, margin

I am relatively new to Android UI. I always get confuse in providing margin to different view like should i provide bottom margin or should i use top margin(to  view below it). Also should i use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout if both can solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: I find LinearLayout to be much less of a pain to use. For simple layouts it's probably sufficient. However, if you find your views are nested deeply, RelativeLayout can help you keep things shallow, which is said to improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

It Depends on your need

**Linear Vs Relative**

If you just want to stack your `TextView` and `Button` horizontally or vertically you should go with `LinearLayout`.
If you want to make a layout that is more complex for example you can have an `ImageView` covering all of the screen and `Button` over the `ImageView` or if you want your layout elements to be stack on corners or at bottom, `RelativeLayout` is your Guy.

**Top margin vs Bottom Margin**

It doesn't make much a difference its a personal preference, I Use margin-bottom on first element rather than margin-top for second element.

Answer (score 2):

One noticeable difference is when you are working with `Show layout bounds` during development. You can see here those pink coloration indicate that it is using margin on its view while padding has no coloration. Recently I prefer to use padding if applicable with my requirements as it seems more cleaner to inspect UI when `Show layout bounds` is enabled from Developer option.

The image is not mine and was just use as a quick sample.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps try embedding the screen shot in the post rather than linking to the screen shot.

Comment: @benhorgen You need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: Good call; I failed to realize that.

Answer (score 1):

If both Linear and RelativeLayout will solve your layout, then you should use Linear as it is faster to render.

With regards to top vs. bottom Margin. That's entirely your preference and how you want to think about the elements. Does Item A always sit 40dp above the next item or does Item B always sit 40dp below the previous item?